# How to create a log file using selenium webdriver and C#?

Tags: c#, webdriver

How to create a log file using selenium webdriver? I had created a log file using selenium RC. IN selenium RC I had created an HTML log file with screenshots and error messages. I used the following code in selenium RC.

`selenium.CaptureEntirePageScreenshot(screenShotDirectory + "\" + "wrong username and password.png","");

string path = "Screenshot\wrong username and password.png";

Sw.WriteLine("**Wrong username and password**
");
`

How can I create same HTML log file using selenium Webdriver? What code in C# should i write?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the .NET bindings, you'll want something like the following:

```
// Assumes driver is a WebDriver instance that implements ITakesScreenshot
// N.B., to be completely correct, you should check for a successful cast
// by adding a null check for screenshotDriver.
ITakesScreenshot screenshotDriver = driver as ITakesScreenshot;
Screenshot screenCapture = screenshotDriver.GetScreenshot();
screenCapture.SaveAsFile(screenShotDirectory + "\\" + "wrongUserNameAndPassword.png", 
    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```